# Как выровнять картинку относительно другой?

Tags: android, java

Сейчас у меня такой кода

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/item_ad_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/marker_ad_image"
        android:src="@drawable/marker_ad"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Но тогда выглядит это следующим образом [image]
А мне нужно, чтобы маркер был прям поверх картинки, а не выровнен по краю родителя (элемент GridView). При этом

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
```

Поставит картинку сбоку, а не поверх. Как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ларчик то просто открывался, оказывается

```
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_ad_image"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/item_ad_image"
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/item_ad_image"
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы накладывать элемент один над другим используется FrameLayoyt, как корневой элемент. В вашем случае можно для картинок задать android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"